# What is the most effective way of Inserting Python dictionaries / lists into SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, json, dictionary, insert

Imagine you have a key-value Python dictionary (or list) with larger amounts of items. Let’s say you’re reading a bigger JSON file and you’d like to store it’s contents into MySQL table with keys as names of columns and values as values itself.

JSON Example:

```
"display_location": {
    "city":"Bratislava",
    "state_name":"Slovakia",
    "country_iso3166":"SK",
    "latitude":"48.20000076",
    "longitude":"17.20000076",
}
```

Then it is quite inefficient to write SQL insert like this manually:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (city, state_name, country_iso3166, latitude, longitude) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')
% (Bratislava, Slovakia, SK, 48.20000076, 17.20000076);
```

(Well, it's ok with five values, but imagine there are for example five hundreds of them.)

Is there any Python class / method for effective and short-stringed SQL insert? I wrote this piece of code:

```
for key,value in list.iteritems():
  value_type = type(value)
    if value_type is unicode:
      vars_to_sql.append(value.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
      keys_to_sql.append(key.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    else:
      vars_to_sql.append(value)
      keys_to_sql.append(key)

keys_to_sql = ', '.join(keys_to_sql)
```

After that the insert looks much more simple:

```
INSERT INTO conditions_bratislava(%s) VALUES %r" % (keys_to_sql,  tuple(vars_to_sql),)
```

There can be thousands of values and you will still be fine with this one insert statement.

*Note that condition which will decode Unicode strings, so you won’t have “u” letters before the each value.*

So, is there any more effective and prepared class or method how to insert many values in the same simple approach with short INSERT string?

Comment: If you do want to use a relational database, maybe use the upcoming PostgreSQL 9.2 which has a native JSON datatype.

Answer (score 5):

If your data is structured like that, it would lend itself more towards a document orientated database (Mongo/Couch etc...)

You can get away with something like this... I think using `repr` is being a little too clever...

```
insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO conditions_bratislava(%s) values(%s)'
cols = ', '.join(somedict)
vals = ', '.join('?' * len(somedict)) # or whatever qparam is required
to_execute = insert_sql % (cols, vals)
some_cursor.execute(to_execute, somedict.values())
```

On a side note:

```
value_type = type(value)
if value_type is unicode:
```

Should be written as:

```
if isinstance(value, unicode):
```

Comment: If the dict is modified in a second thread, this might yield incorrect order of the values or too many values. I'd go with named parameters instead and passing the whole dictionary to cursor.execute.

Comment: @möter I was offering the "more correct" version of what the OP was doing. I do agree that using named parameters is somewhat better in general though. I would also hope that anyone using threads would be wary enough to be using locking.